# Classe não se extende de outra

Tags: php

Olá estou tendo problemas ao usar `extends` em uma certa `class`, veja meu código abaixo:

Classe do template:

```
<?php

class Template {
    private $_strings = array();
    private $_template;

    public function set($file) {
        $path = 'templates/' . DEFAULT_THEME . '/' . $file . '.tpl.php';

        if (!empty($path)) {
            if (file_exists($path)) {
                $this->_template = file_get_contents($path);
            } else {
                die("<b>Template error: </b> arquivo não encontrado: <i>{$file}.tpl.php</i>");
            }
        }
    }

    public function assign($string, $toReplace) {
        if (!empty($string)) {
            $this->_strings[$string] = $toReplace;
        }
    }

    public function show() {
        if (count($this->_strings) > 0) {
            foreach ($this->_strings as $key => $value) {
                $this->_template = str_replace('{' . $key . '}', $value, $this->_template);
            }
        }

        return $this->_template;
    }
}
```

Classe usando `extends`

```
class Spinxo extends Template {

    public function __construct() {
        $tpl = new Template;
    }

    public function load() {
        global $tpl;
        $tpl->assign('web_title', 'titulo do site');
    }
}
```

O que eu quero, quero que essa class `Spinxo` carregue todas as configurações, esta é minha home:

```
$tpl = new Template();
$spx = new Spinxo($tpl);

$url = (isset($_GET['url'])) ? $_GET['url'] : 'home';

switch ($url) {
    case 'home':
        $tpl->set('home');
        $spx->load();
        break;
}


echo $tpl->show();
```

Como podem ver eu estou instanciando meu objeto com a variável `$tpl` quando eu tiro o `extends` da minha classe Spinxo e uso `global $tpl` funciona... não sei se consegui explicar, mas quem entender por favor responda. :D

Comment: Pra que passar uma instância de uma da classe pai para a classe filha? Não entendi o que você deseja com isso...

Comment: Foi só pra tentar explicar, eu queria usar `$this->assign()` mas meu código só funciona quando eu uso `$tpl->assign()` usando o `global $tpl` e eu não queria isso :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está implementado de forma errada sua classe filho. Não entendi o propósito da classe template, mas para o que você quer fazer basta isso:

```
class Spinxo extends Template {

    public function load() {
        $this->assign('web_title', 'titulo do site');
    }
}
```

`Spinxo` já tem o método `assign` herdado de `Template`. Na hora de utilizar a classe você também não precisa passar `Template` como dependência de `Spinxo`:

```
$spx = new Spinxo();

$url = (isset($_GET['url'])) ? $_GET['url'] : 'home';

switch ($url) {
    case 'home':
        $spx->set('home');
        $spx->load();
        break;
}


echo $spx->show();
```

Comment: Ué, por que eu fiz desta forma e não tinha retornado o mesmo resultado, agora retornou?, sei lá sei que isso resolveu meu problema

Comment: Entendi agora, eu tinha feito assim: `$tpl->show` e vc passou $spx, correto obrigado.

Comment: Procure utilizar nomes de variáveis mais significativos @GuilhermeSpinXO. Ajuda a visualizar melhor esse tipo de problema :)

Answer (score -2):

Coloque um `require_once` no código aonde você dará o `extends`

```
<?php

require_once("template.class.php");

class Spinxo extends Template {

    public function __construct() {
        $tpl = new Template;
    }

    public function load() {
        global $tpl;
        $tpl->assign('web_title', 'titulo do site');
    }
}
```

Comment: Ele está incluindo o arquivo, o meu problema é que eu só consigo fazer com que a classe funcione quando eu uso `global $tpl`, eu gostaria de apenas usar `$this->assign()` ao invés de `$tpl->assign()`, não vou precisar incluir, já estou usando `__autoload();`